# Is there a way to format snmptrap?

Tags: formatting, snmp, snmp-trap

I have a raspberry pi running raspbian set up as a client, and debian running the server. I can recieve and read the snmptrap.out just fine, but It's transmitting 150 bytes per message. As it's sending over 3G I want to shorten the snmptrap size as much as possible.

Is there a way to arbitrarily set the formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the SNMP TRAP format can not be changed as it has fixed structure defined in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1157